# Can you change the action of a form without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I was hoping to do the whole degrading gracefully thing without making my form have ugly extra buttons and breaking up my program structure with another layer of indirection. I really doubt that this is possible, but is there an option I am unaware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, what is coded is coded. But if you have access to a server side language, it should be easy to have one action (e.g. a php script) that includes the right file based on a pressed button or selected input value.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but one can dream ;-)